# How to copy files from tablet to PC - Not all files show up in PC

Tags: file-transfer, usb-connection-mode, motorola-xoom

When I connect my Xoom to my PC via USB cable I get a Xoom "Portable Media Player" showing up in my Windows Explorer.  When I browse the drive, I can only see half the folders compared to if I browse the SD card directly from within Astro file manager on the Xoom.

Why aren't all files and folders showing up?  In Android (3.2), I've tried copying a file from a "hidden" folder to a folder that I can actually see on the PC but the file does not show up.

Someone suggested it was because it didn't get mounted as "USB Mass Storage".

How can I copy the files?

(same functionality works fine from my HTC Desire)

Comment: Are the missing files actually on the external SD card, or are they in the Xoom's internal `/sdcard` directory?

Comment: I have not installed any external SD card, so I assume it's the internal memory.  The files can be seen in /sdcard subdirectory (as well as /mnt/sdcard).  However, not all files seen there are visible in my PC

Comment: Do those hidden folders start with a dot "."? Have you tried enabling options in windows explorer to show hidden files?

Comment: @Audrius Windows doesn't hide folders starting with a dot, they have to be marked as hidden in their properties.

Comment: Does Windows Explorer show it with a phone or PMP icon instead of a drive icon? If so I would suspect onik's answer is correct.

Comment: Windows filesystem cannot create files with dot in the beginning.. So such folders, (including .nomedia files) won't be copied over.

Comment: @Power-Inside What are you talking about? In Windows, files beginning with a dot are handled as normal files, there's nothing special about them, and they definitely can be created. Just go to any explorer window and `File -> New -> Text Document` and name it `.test.txt`. No problems.

Comment: @onik We are talking about .nomedia files here.. try to create a file/folder with the name as ".test" NOT ".test.txt". It won't work. Hence, .nomedia files cannot exist in windows filesystem.

Comment: @Power-Inside That is not a restriction of the file system, it's a restriction of Windows Explorer. Try this: Open Notepad, type something, `File -> Save...` and select `Save as type: All files`. Then enter the filename `.nomedia` and save. Or open a command prompt and try `echo This is a dotfile example > .dotfile`. How do you think most Linux-based apps would still use dot-prefix folders for their settings after being ported to Windows if NTFS wouldn't support them?

Comment: @onik  Thanks for clarifying. for a moment there i thought the file system just didnt support it because I copied a folder from my android using copy-paste and the destination didnt have the .nomedia copied over!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [WiFi File Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dooblou.WiFiFileExplorer&feature=search_result) (also available in pro version with more features). It reads your SD card just like Astro does, allows you to view it from a computer browser, and does not require root. You may be able to view your files from here, and if so, you can download them via WiFi network.

Let us know if it works! :)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a WiFi connection at home!

Comment: ouch :/ let Mr know if you get one then! :)

Answer (score 1):

you may try install the android SDK and use adb-pull under command-line.

Comment: Sounds like bit of an overkill :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple painless can be with [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) application where you can share files between various platforms. No need for cable just wireless access ;)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Android versions 3.1+ support [MTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol)  for file transfers. This is a better protocol than USB Mass Storage for media files (music, photos, videos) but won't necessarily work with all files as well. Probably since this mode is meant for media transfer, the system and data folders are hidden from the user.

Comment: Strange, since the files that I'm not able to access are in fact images!

Comment: Got a Samsung Galaxy Tab a couple of days ago and it uses MTP, but I can see all the same folders on it. So I don't think it's a MTP problem anymore. At least not a general Android-MTP problem, don't know if Motorola or Samsung use modified protocol stacks.